# Renaming a certain cells twice but there is an error (ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rename two cells that fulfil a certain condition.

I wanted to rename the serial number for 2 items to be 14 and 19.

```py
AS= pd.ExcelFile('A.xlsx')

B = pd.read_excel(AS, sheet_name='3')
B.loc[B['Unnamed: 1']=='FA0101', B['Serial No.']]=19
B.loc[B['Unnamed: 1']=='FA0296', B['Serial No.']]=14
```

However, when I run this code with both, there is an error.

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is there an index which has duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`B.loc[B['Unnamed: 1']=='FA0101', B['Serial No.']]=19`

to

`B.loc[B['Unnamed: 1']=='FA0101', 'Serial No.']=19`

If your just want to assign cell value.

You got `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.`. I guess you have duplicate index in your excel file, but I don't know how can you do it without argument `index_col = 0` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np
B['Serial No.'] = (np.select([B['Unnamed: 1']=='FA0101', B['Unnamed: 1']=='FA0296'], 
                             [19,14], 
                             default=0)) #change this to whatever you  want the alternative result to be if condition not met
```